# $_GET is empty after defining a rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress

Hello Wordpress ninjas,

I am new to wordpress develpoment. I define a **rewrite rule** (with a tag), similar to what you can find in examples [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag).

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%filterx_location%', '([^&/]+)', 'filterx_location=');
$wp_rewrite->add_rule('property-location/(.+)$','index.php?post_type=property&filterx_location=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Now, the problem is, that when the query is completed (the page is shown), the filterx_location paramater is not set. In fact, `var_dump($_GET)` gives me an `array(0) { }`.

I have a black out or something, seems like something simple I miss here, just cannot figure it out :-/

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

what is even stranger is that when I generate rewrite rules with:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%filterx_location%', '([^/]+)', 'filterx_location=');
$permalink_prefix = 'property-location'; 
$permalink_structure = '%filterx_location%/'; 
$rewrite_rules = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($permalink_prefix.'/'.$permalink_structure, EP_ALL, true, true, true, true, true);
```

I see a bunch of generated urls matches and redirects, if I print them. One of them is:

```
property-location/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ => index.php?filterx_location=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&post_type=property
```

I add all the generated urls with:

```
foreach($rewrite_rules as $regex => $redirect) {
    if(strpos($redirect, 'attachment=') === false) {
        //add the post_type to the rewrite rule
        $redirect .= '&post_type=property';
    }

    //turn all of the $1, $2,... variables in the matching regex into $matches[] form
    if(0 < preg_match_all('@\$([0-9])@', $redirect, $matches)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
            $redirect = str_replace($matches[0][$i], '$matches['.$matches[1][$i].']', $redirect);
        }
    }
    //add the rewrite rule to wp_rewrite
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule($regex, $redirect, 'top');
}
```

And If I go to the URL `/property-location/madrid/page/2/` then the query_vars correctly do have ["paged"]=> int(2). **But the filterx_location is totally ignored!**

Comment: by the way, I do call `flush_rewrite_rules();` after this, but still the same result. On the newly opened page I call `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);`, but for some reason the tag that I defined does not appear in the returned array at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it working, in a strange turn of events. First I replaced

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%filterx_location%', '([^/]+)', 'filterx_location=');
```

with:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%filterx_location%', '([^/]+)', 'filterx_location=');
```

I noticed those are two different things. I took a look into the wordpress code of add_rewrite_tag:

```
function add_rewrite_tag($tagname, $regex) {
    //validation
    if ( strlen($tagname) < 3 || $tagname[0] != '%' || $tagname[strlen($tagname)-1] != '%' )
        return;

    $qv = trim($tagname, '%');
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var($qv);
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag($tagname, $regex, $qv . '=');
}
```

I thought the "add_query_var" part might be essential.

**But it still did not work!**

So what I did finally was add another call to `add_query_var()` after the `add_rewrite_tag()` call:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%filterx_location%', '([^/]+)', 'filterx_location=');
$wp->add_query_var('filterx_location');
```

and only then everything started to work. Initially I assumed that `$_GET` should be holding my variable, but then even calls to `get_query_var('filterx_location')` were empty. Now it get the right stuff.